# Javascript Email Validation from Form Field suddenly doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, validation, email

Working on a web page which used to have a working email validation, but after adding in a few additional features it suddenly no longer works. The page shouldn't proceed unless all fields are valid, everything is basically client-side if you're wondering why it's a bit of a weird website.

Originally the e-mail validation worked for if the field was blank or did not have an '@' and '.' following it, using the code:

```
  if (d==null || d=="")
  {
  document.forms["registration"]["email"].focus();
  alert("Please enter your email address");
  return false;
}
else
    {
        var emailAddress = d;
        var atLoc = emailAddress.indexOf("@",1);
        var dotLoc = emailAddress.indexOf(".",atLoc+2);
        var len = emailAddress.length;

        if (atLoc > 0 && dotLoc > 0 && len > dotLoc+2)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Invalid E-mail address format! Please enter your e-mail address again.");
            document.forms["registration"]["email"].focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

However, added with the entire code of:

```
    function validateForm(){

{
  var f=document.forms["registration"]["FirstName"].value;
  var a=document.forms["registration"]["Surname"].value;
  var b=document.forms["registration"]["address"].value;
  var c=document.forms["registration"]["post"].value;
  var d=document.forms["registration"]["email"].value;
  var z=document.forms["registration"]["password"].value;

  if (f==null || f=="")
  {
  document.forms["registration"]["FirstName"].focus();
  alert("Please enter your first name");

  return false;
}
if (a==null || a=="")
  {
  document.forms["registration"]["Surname"].focus();
  alert("Please enter your surname");
  return false;
}


if (b==null || b=="")
  {
  alert("Please enter your address");
  document.forms["registration"]["address"].focus();
  return false;
}
if (c==null || c=="")
  {
  alert("Please enter your postcode");
  document.forms["registration"]["post"].focus();
  return false;
}
if (d==null || d=="")
  {
  document.forms["registration"]["email"].focus();
  alert("Please enter your email address");
  return false;
}
else
    {
        var emailAddress = d;
        var atLoc = emailAddress.indexOf("@",1);
        var dotLoc = emailAddress.indexOf(".",atLoc+2);
        var len = emailAddress.length;

        if (atLoc > 0 && dotLoc > 0 && len > dotLoc+2)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Invalid E-mail address format! Please enter your e-mail address again.");
            document.forms["registration"]["email"].focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

}
}
```

It no longer works...? Puzzled, any help appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do invalid emails get accepted? Do you get errors in your browser console? Do the other field validations work? Or...? _"everything is basically client-side"_ - But you _do_ revalidate server-side before storing anything in a database, right? You can't trust client-side validation on its own. Also, what's with the variable names? `f` for first name, but then `a` for surname and `b` for address? Are you _trying_ to make your code confusing? Finally, note that you don't need the `==null` tests, because a form element's `.value` will never be `null`.

Comment: The verification doesn't work, so anything can pass through the text field. All other verifications result in an alert button being displayed and a return fail. I want it to do the same for the e-mail - which seemed to work before. 

I'm very aware of the implications and issues with doing this client-side, but there is no server-side/back-end database in this code.